# How to stop Vim from indent template in C/C++?

Tags: indentation

I have piece of sample code (copied from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf))

```
//some lines of code

    template <typename ... Args>
std::string string_format (
        const std::string& format,
        Args ... args )
{
    int size_s = std::snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ... ) + 1;
    if( size_s <= 0 ){ throw std::runtime_error( "Error during formatting." ); }
    auto size = static_cast<size_t>( size_s );
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] );
    std::snprintf( buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ... );
    return std::string( buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1 );
}
```

For some reason, the line containing "template" is always indented.

How to stop this behavior?

I can see some relevant settings as follows: I can reproduce the problem with `autoindent`, `cindent`, `nosmartindent`, and `indentexpr=`.

---

**Update**
The problem is solved by using:

```
set cinoptions=t0
```

Thank [Vivian De Smedt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/40282/40979) for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the `cindent`  indentation using the `cinoptions` (`:help cinoptions`).

To not have the return type indented you can do:

```
set cinoptions=t0
```

More information with `:help cino-t`

Comment: Thank you. It works!

Comment: You are Welcome :-) Thanks for the feedback.